# Javascript & JQuery In The Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to web development and have been writing my pages using Javascript. I've done some research and found that JQuery will actually provide me with better more flexible functionality.

My question is if I was to use JQuery could I have it within the same document as my Javascript or can you only have one or the other?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, jQuery is just JavaScript that someone else has written.

Comment: jQuery is not a language - it is a library written in javaScript that provides cross-browser solutions for common pain points in javaScript.

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is just a javascript library. It's just like any other javascript library, yours included, meaning you can write all the javascript you want, alongside jQuery.

Comment: _"I've done some research and found that JQuery will actually provide me with better more flexible functionality"_ - Given that jQuery is written in JavaScript it can't do anything that you couldn't do yourself in JavaScript. So it doesn't provide you with more functionality than JavaScript, it just saves you having to re-invent the wheel: it provides functions that you'd otherwise likely have to write for yourself.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery is simply a set of tools which are built in JavaScript which are designed to give you a better way to interact with the DOM in a cross-browser compliant fashion. It isn't that they are compatible, jQuery **is** JavaScript - so yes, you can use them together all you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write jQuery without writing javascript as jQuery is a library written in javascript.

When you're coding in jQuery, you're coding in Javascript.

This means of course that everything you do using jQuery could be done (sometimes with pain, especially if you're not experimented) in [Vanilla Javascript](http://vanilla-js.com/).

JQuery is especially useful to

- deal with browsers differences
- simplify DOM access code

But it's never the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty i rather using jQuery and i will explain why in a moment. Basically they are the same thing where jQuery is just a framework of JavaScript. To break it down you have to look at how each one uses elements and calls functions.

### **jQuery**

```
$('#container');
```

### **JavaScript**

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
```

or even if you want to add, remove and toggle classes

### **jQuery**

```
$('#box').addClass('wrap');
$('#box').removeClass('wrap');
$('#box').toggleClass('wrap');
```

### **JavaScript**

```
var container = document.querySelector('#box');
container.classList.add('wrap');
container.classList.remove('wrap');
container.classList.toggle('wrap');
```

Obviously in some cases JavaScript can be better and more lightweight for a site, the question is not necessarily “Which is better?” but “Which is better when?” JavaScript’s new Selector API goes a long way toward making vanilla JavaScript nearly as easy to work with as jQuery. In cases where we can get things done without loading the jQuery library, our sites will travel lighter and perform a bit snappier.

They take-away: The jQuery library is fantastic when you need it, but in each case, we should pause to ask: “Do I really need jQuery in this case? — Or can I get it done in straight JavaScript?”

Hope this helps anyone interested.
-Epik-

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have it in the same document.

jQuery is only a library, meaning someone has written a load of functions that you can use. It's kind of in the name - you're querying their Javascript in one line for something that would usually take you an hour to write out.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a library written in javascript so you definitely can reference jQuery ands still use native javascript.

Think of jQuery as a library to hide the complexity of native javascript and browser compatibility issues (especially when it comes to DOM manipulation). It doesn't replace javascript, it just provide a higher-level view to make life easier for you.